# Copy data from each row in first column into a html hyperlink in the last column using Sed, Awk, etc

Tags: csv, awk, sed

What i'm trying to do is copy the first data from each row in the first column and put it into the hyperlink in the last column created

This is an example of a file i get each day. Let's call this file ***input.csv*** and i want to transform it into ***output.csv***

P.S. The number of rows varies each day.

**INPUT.CSV**

```
number|name|age|gender
B24|mike|22|male
B65|john|45|male
B74|jane|29|female
```

This is how i want it to look like:

**OUTPUT.CSV**

```
number|name|age|gender|website
B24|mike|22|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B24>B24</a>
B65|john|45|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>
B74|jane|29|female|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>
```

To make it neater, i put some variables in place

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMBER=(data from the "number" column of each corresponding row in the input.csv file)
URL=https://www.abcdef.com/search?query=$NUMBER

awk -F"|" 'BEGIN { OFS = "|" } {$5="<a href='$URL'>'$NUMBER'</a>"; print}' input.csv > output.csv
```

So far, i've been able to do this which just creates a new column and repeats the hyperlink all through the column and the result of my failed output is below:

**FAILED RESULT**

```
number|name|age|gender|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/search?query=></a>
B65|john|45|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>
B74|jane|29|female|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Could you please confirm if your expected output's last line should be `B74|jane|29|female|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>`? Looks like your input has `B74` but output has F74 and F24? Please confirm once.

Comment: sorry that was a typo , fixing it now. and it works.

Awesome!! i appreciate the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
FNR==1{
  print $0,"website"
  next
}
{
  print $0,"<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query="$1">"$1"</a>"
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution*** adding 1 more variation of `awk` code above where making variable named `firstHeader` which has value of `<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=` just in case we need to change it in future we need not to change main program then.

```
awk -v firstHeader="<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=" -v secheader="</a>" '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
FNR==1{
  print $0,"website"
  next
}
{
  print $0,firstHeader $1">"$1 secheader
}
'  Input_file
```

***OR*** use ternary operator condition little tweak in above version:

```
awk -v firstHeader="<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=" -v secheader="</a>" '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
  print $0, (FNR==1 ? "website" : firstHeader $1">"$1 secheader)
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: why not simply =============== ========== ===================== =============
`BEGIN {…} $++NF = FNR==1 ? "website" : firstHeader $1">"$1 secheader`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto, IMHO for me printing values looks simple than adding a field(which could be done in some other cases). Good that you have added your version, cheers.

Comment: then make it `{ print $0, (FNR==1 ? "website" : firstHeader $1">"$1 secheader) }` - it would retain all the original functionality of ur code without adding a new field

Comment: i have a quick question @RavinderSingh13. what if, instead of creating a new column with the hyperlinks, i just replace the data in the first column with the hyperlinks? how would i go about that?

Comment: @igbins09, I would like to request you to please open a new question(since one post/thread one question is encouraged else it may confuse future users IMHO) with all details and your code efforts and we could definitely discuss it there, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13. okay, just did that

Answer (score 4):

This `sed` should work for you:

```bash
sed -E '1s/$/|website/; 1!s~^([^|]+).*~&|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=\1>\1</a>~' file

number|name|age|gender|website
B24|mike|22|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B24>B24</a>
B65|john|45|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>
B74|jane|29|female|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
number|name|age|gender
B24|mike|22|male
B65|john|45|male
B74|jane|29|female
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NR==1{print $0,"website";next}{printf "%s|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=%s>%s</a>\n", $0, $1, $1}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
number|name|age|gender|website
B24|mike|22|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B24>B24</a>
B65|john|45|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>
B74|jane|29|female|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that pipe character (`|`) is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`). For first line I print line as is followed by `website`, for all other I use `printf` with string with 3 places to fill denoted by `%s`: 1st for already existing fields, 2nd for query value, 3rd for `a` tag text, which I fill using whole using line as is (`$0`) and first field (`$1`) and first field (`$1`). Note that I newline character (`\n`) at end, as `printf` does not furnish it.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 3):

Based on the line number, you might also append a pipe and either *website* or the hyperlink at the end of the line.

```
awk -F"|" 'sub(/$/,(NR==1?"|website":"|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query="$1">"$1"</a>"))' input.csv > output.csv
```

The content of `output.csv`:

```
number|name|age|gender|website
B24|mike|22|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B24>B24</a>
B65|john|45|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>
B74|jane|29|female|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

keep it simple :

> ```
> {m,g}awk -F'^$' '
> NF < NR ? (ORS =(_=sprintf("%.3s",$__))">"(_)"</a>\n")^!++NF \
>         : $!NF = $__ "|website"' OFS='|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query='
> ```

```
number|name|age|gender|website
B24|mike|22|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B24>B24</a>
B65|john|45|male|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>
B74|jane|29|female|<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>
```