# Replace First column with hyperlink plus the inital data embedded in it

Tags: csv, awk, sed

This is a follow up question from [Copy data from each row in first column into a html hyperlink in the last column using Sed, Awk, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73523467/copy-data-from-each-row-in-first-column-into-a-html-hyperlink-in-the-last-column)

What i'm trying to do is replace the data in the first column and put it into the following hyperlink

This is an example of a file i get each day. Let's call this file ***input.csv*** and i want to transform it into ***output.csv***

P.S. The number of rows varies each day.

**INPUT.CSV**

```
number|name|age|gender
B24|mike|22|male
B65|john|45|male
B74|jane|29|female
```

This is how i want it to look like:

**OUTPUT.CSV**

```
number|name|age|gender
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B24>B24</a>|mike|22|male
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>|john|45|male
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>|jane|29|female
```

i tried to continue from a previous solution that worked but this has the column at the end so i thought i could add a new awk statement to cut out the last column and replace with the first column but what i tried didn't work

```
'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==1{print $0,"link";next} {print $0,"<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query="$1">"$1"</a>"}'
```

what i tried which didn't work:

```
'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==1{print $0,"slink";next} {print $0, "<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query="$1">"$1"</a>"} {temp=$NF; $NF = ""; sub(",$", ""); print temp, $0}'
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts/codes else you may get close votes on your question, thank you.

Comment: i haven't really tried anything major yet. i only brought it to you because you helped with the first one and suggested i create a new question as a follow up to the first one

Comment: You could try something like: `awk -v firstHeader="<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=" -v secheader="</a>" 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } {match($0,/\|.*/);print $0, (FNR==1 ? "website" : firstHeader $1">"$1 secheader) substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file` since you haven't added your tried code so I am posting it here, cheers.

Comment: Regarding `i haven't really tried anything major yet.` - try something first then ask a question if you need help with that, don't ask us to do it for you without even trying to do it yourself. See [ask].

Comment: @igbins09: Even if it is an extension of earlier problem you should still add an attempted code to avoid close vote/downvotes. Even the existing code that you had can be shown as an attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @igbins09, Thanks for adding your efforts, I have added mine solution also, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: OP has posted attempted code in most recent edit therefore this question may be reopened now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `sed` should work for you:

```bash
sed '1!s~[^|]*~<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=&>&</a>~' file

number|name|age|gender
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B24>B24</a>|mike|22|male
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>|john|45|male
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>|jane|29|female
```

Or this `awk`:

```bash
awk 'NR > 1 {sub(/[^|]+/, "<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=&>&</a>")} 1' file

number|name|age|gender
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B24>B24</a>|mike|22|male
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>|john|45|male
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>|jane|29|female
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ url=https://www.abcdef.com/search?query=
$ sed "1!s~^[^|]*~${url}&>&</a>~woutput.csv" input_file
$ cat output.csv
number|name|age|gender
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B24>B24</a>|mike|22|male
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B65>B65</a>|john|45|male
<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=B74>B74</a>|jane|29|female
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and efforts please try following `awk` code. Using `match` function here to get values from very first occurrence of `|` in line to end of line and keeping rest of the functionality same for code.

```
awk -v firstHeader="<a href=https://www.abcdef.com/query=" -v secheader="</a>" '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
  match($0,/\|.*/)
  print $0, (FNR==1 ? "website" : firstHeader $1">"$1 secheader) substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```